# How can I know the temporal document ingestion date

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10

I want to know the [temporal document](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/temporal/intro) ingestion date. Is there any function to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a function available to achieve that directly.

You could enable the **maintain last-modified** on the database.

https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/admin-guide/en/databases/understanding-databases/database-settings/document-and-directory-settings.html

> **maintain last modified**  Creates and updates the **last-modified** property each time a document is created or updated. The default is `false`.

However, it is not enabled by default and it would not be a reliable insert/ingest dateTime value, as any change to the doc would bump that dateTime value.

If you want to track the document insert dateTime, it may be best to add that information to the document, add it to the metadata inserted with the document, or a [document-property](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/properties#chapter).